# List index out of range

Tags: python

I have a list of pairs of words, and am trying to prepare them as data for NetworkX to read. Part of the script is iterating over the pairs to map them to id numbers (see code below). This code throws an `Index out of range`-error that I need to get past. What is the mistake here?

```
coocs = [['parttim;work'], ['parttim;work'],['parttim;visit'], ['parttim;site'], ['parttim;uncl'], ['parttim;home'], ['parttim;onlin']]
unique_coocs = list(set([row[0] for row in coocs]))  # remove redundance
ids = list(enumerate(unique_coocs))  # creates a list of tuples with unique ids and their names for each word in the network
keys = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(unique_coocs)}  # creates a dictionary(hash map) that maps each id to the words
links = []  # creates a blank list

for row in coocs:  # maps all of the names in the list to their id number
    try:
        links.append({keys[row[0]]: keys[row[1]]})
    except:
        links.append({row[0]: row[1]})
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: This: `links.append({row[0]: row[1]})`

Comment: It would help to give the entire error message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works fine

```
 for row in coocs:  # maps all of the names in the list to their id number
     links.append({row[0]: keys[row[0]]})

>>> links
[{'parttim;work': 2}, {'parttim;work': 2}, {'parttim;visit': 3}, {'parttim;site': 4}, {'parttim;uncl': 0}, {'parttim;home': 5}, {'parttim;onlin': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake occurs at `row`, because `len(row)` in always `1` here, So you cannot use the `index number 1` which is `row[1]`

Corrected code is,

```
for row in coocs:
    links.append(row[0]+':'+str(keys[row[0]]))
print links
```

Output:

> > ['parttim;work:2', 'parttim;work:2', 'parttim;visit:3', 'parttim;site:4', 'parttim;uncl:0', 'parttim;home:5', 'parttim;onlin:1']